# Transform a string separated by semi colons with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string (which is a time) like such `01:02:3` that I would like to get a total number value in seconds. So expected output would be 3723.

```
const time = "1:02:3";

const timeNumeric = time.split(':').map(item => { 
  return Number(item)
});

function total() {
  var totalTime = 0;
  if (timeNumeric.length = 3) {
    const num1 = timeNumeric[0] * 3600
    const num2 = timeNumeric[1] * 60
    const num3 = timeNumeric[2]
    totalTime = num1 + num2 + timeNumeric[2]
  } else if (timeNumeric.length == 2) {
    const num2 = timeNumeric[1] * 60
    const num3 = timeNumeric[2]
    totalTime = num2 + num3
  } else if (timeNumeric.length == 1) {
    const num3 = timeNumeric[2]
    totalTime = num3
  } else {
    console.log('nothing')
  }
  console.log(totalTime)
}
```

Keep in mind, the value in the string might not always be 3 numbers, could be `2:45` or `30`, which then the 3rd option value would not require any calculation.

Comment: What is exactly the question?

Comment: Apologies. Edited question to make more sense.

Comment: So if the string is "2:45", is that 2 minutes and 45 seconds or 2 hours and 45 minutes?

Comment: that would be 2mins and 45secs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was right except for the current number. When you use `*` JavaScript attempts to convert to a number. However when you use `+` JavaScript attempts to convert to a String if one of the two variables is a String.

```js
var getSeconds = function(time) {
    return time.split(':').reduce(function(prev, curr) { 
        return prev * 60 + parseInt(curr, 10)
    }, 0)
}

var total = getSeconds('01:02:03')
var total2 = getSeconds('2:34')

console.log(total, total2) // 3723 154
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the split strings into numbers before you can use the reduce function to multiply them out. Something like this:

```
const strNums = "01:02:3";
const multiplier = 3;

const arrayStrNums = strNums.split(':').map( item => {
    return Number(item) * multiplier;
});

const total = arrayStrNums.reduce((a, b) => {
    return a + b;
})

console.log(total);
```

Comment: In general I would prefer `parseInt(item, 10)`. Although if `Number`-like behavior is better, `+item` also coerces to a `Number` and is shorter.